# Request failed. Column 'Project Phase' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, item

```
function fetchProjectData(projectName, callbackOnSuccess) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("path to site");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project Overview');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+projectName+'</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Project Phase, Project Manager, Start Date, End Date)');

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var itemObject = {
            title: oListItem.get_item('Start Date')
        };
        callbackOnSuccess(itemObject);
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));        
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from a list element.

Code above returns the error:

> Request failed. Column 'Project Phase' does not exist. It may have
>   been deleted by another user. /projects/Lists/Project Overview

- This column exists.
- Project Phase is the internal name.
- It hasn't been renamed.
- Its a choice column.

Comment: You should use the Internal Name of the columns, not the display name. Internal names can not contain blanks so that can not be the correct internal name

Comment: @RobertLindgren I am, Project Phase is the internal name. I made the column myself, I've also retrieved all internal names for that list and Project Phase pops up.

Comment: Project Phase might be the display name, but not the internal name

Comment: Go to list settings and hover mouse over "Project Phase" and check the URL query string "Field=..."

Comment: @AmalHashim Did this, shows me the XSL version: "Project_x0020_Phase". Where am i to specify this? In the include string at load or in the success function? Maybe both?

Comment: You must use that internal name in both the `Include()` and when trying to get the value of the field in the success method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function fetchProjectData(projectName, callbackOnSuccess) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("path to site");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project Overview');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+projectName+'</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Project_x0020_Phase, Project_x0020_Manager, Start_x0020_Date, End_x0020_Date)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var itemObject = {
            title: oListItem.get_item('Start_x0020_Date')
        };
        callbackOnSuccess(itemObject);
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Now getting the message Request failed. Column 'Project_x0020_Manager' does not exist. This field is a people picker field.

Comment: @ThomasLindauer check the internal name by checking the list settings.. then replace it with what you see in the URL

Comment: Upvoting because you show how to pull properties with spaces in them.